# Difference between having resources in Resx file and folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resources

I know I can add resources to Resources.resx file and then use it like properties.resources.MyFile.dat.
But what is the difference when I simply add file to Resources folder (setting it to embedded) and Copy to output dir to Always copy and access it like "\Resources\Data\file.dat"?
Also this is another way how to add resources?

Answer (score 1):

There are two core differences:

1. When you have your resources inside a .resources file, they are normally embedded on your assembly (the `.exe` or `.dll` file) instead of having their own file.
2. When the resource is embedded on your assembly, you can rely on the .Net Framework's localization infrastructure to have localized versions of it if the need arises.

In summary:

- For resources you'll need to localize, embed.
- For resources you'll need to change from the program, use stand-alone files.
- For everything else, it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks. Also when I do not use Resources files, I will have the files externally together with my assembly, right?

Comment: Exactly: everything within the `.resource` ends up within the assembly; files thay you set to `Copy to output` are just that: copied to the output directory. All other differences are just consequences of that fact.